# GIS library for ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gis

I am trying to develop an ASP.net MVC website in which I need to show a map (whole world) with several markers and additional information for every marker.

Does anyone know a good library that would support that and which (if possible) also lets me use "offline" maps stored on my own server (open street maps for example).
It will be an intranet application which means in case of google/bing yearly license costs would have to be paid. The customer doesn't want that, but in general the library can be commercial (one-time per server and/or developer fee).

I already had a look at "ThinkGeo Map Suite", any other suggestions or recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharpMap, it's flexible and easy to implement, can use with shapes or from spacial db.

for details... http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/

there is a couple examples who does exactly what you need, so can start from these

exist other libraries but I don't try it, research for another options.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. Do you maybe know if it is possible with sharpmap to use local data downloaded from open-street-map; if it is where can I find an example or a tutorial?

Comment: yeah, shapes can be use it and don't require spacial db or nothing else...
here is the svn repository for an example solution https://sharpmap.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Branches/0.9-GeoJSON/

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

Manifold is a very cheap system which has an basic internet map server framework:

http://www.manifold.net/info/ims.shtml

You already suggested ThinkGeo, I would put it in the same basket as Manifold.  Be sure to evaluate performance and limitations with both packages.

## Discussion

You'd be hard pressed to find a pure NET library for mapping that works well and won't blow out your budget (*see ESRI*).  Depending on your skill level and your knowledge of GIS systems, I would suggest creating your own web map server and just embed it in your web application.

Some good environments for this which I can recommend are:

- MapServer
- GeoServer

As far as displaying and interacting with the map, there are several web based platforms available:

- [GIS SDKs For Web Apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geographic_information_systems_software#Software_development_frameworks_and_libraries_.28for_web_applications.29)

Comment: I haven't heard of Manifold before. Thank you, I will try it soon.